# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not passing url to the next view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm new to Objective-C. I have a table view with a list of urls. When the user clicks on a cell in the table view they are guided to a second view controller with a web view displaying the website. However, when I run the app the web view appears blank. I think the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is the problem. So how do I pass the url to the second view controller?

**ListTableViewController.m**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    FeaturedWebViewController *vc = [[FeaturedWebViewController alloc] init];
    vc.url = cell.textLabel.text;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

**FeaturedWebViewController.m**

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: [self.url stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: I'd double-check that cell.textLabel.text has the correct value; maybe put a stop in the code and make sure that vc.url has the string you're expecting. If that looks right, then the issue is probably in FeaturedWebViewController. Maybe the conversion from String to NSURL is failing? Not sure...please post the code if you're still running into problems.

Comment: We would need to also see the second view controller's code where you use the `.url` value.

Comment: I wouldn't pull data from a cell, get it from the structure that you populate the cell with.

Comment: It definitely looks like `cell.textLabel.text` is nil

Comment: Do you have also a segue on the storyboard, or you just present your `FeaturedWebViewController`manually?

Comment: What is self.url? Show us @property definition. When do you  create NSURLRequest in your controller? Lastly, put two breakpoint to pin point when the value is set and when it's used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your cell.textLabel.text is nil, as WMios said one hour ago.

You should rather get the original data array which popluated your tableview. The cell contents are flushed when it is already displayed. So you cannot get the current displayed cell.textlabel.text when all the cells are reused already;

So,   if you use coredata or popluated mutable array(=listOfItem below), then it would be like this:

```
YourCoreDataSet *yourDataRow = [listOfItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
FeaturedWebViewController *vc = [[FeaturedWebViewController alloc] init];
vc.url = yourDataRow.yourDataFieldHere;
```

//I recommend you  to check with NSLog like this:

```
NSLog(@"sending value: %@, received value: %@",  yourDataRow.yourDataFieldHere, vc.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

A few breakpoints should solve this issue but assuming textLabel.text has the correct url value and that it's a valid url (contains no spaces) the problem is likely that your [self.webView loadRequest:request] is running before you set the url property on FeaturedWebViewController.

Without any more information though it's all speculation. Use the debugger and figure out if you're creating a non-nil NSURL object in [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL].

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** :- Write down this code in FirstVC, .m file.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return mutArryAllUrl.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.lblUrl.text = mutArryAllUrl[indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

SecondVC *aSecondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];

//Here create one NSString Property in SecondVC, name is 'strURL' for getting URL. 
SecondVC.strURL = mutArryAllUrl[indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aSecondVC withDefinedAnimated:YES];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

**Step 2** :- Write down this code in SecondVC, .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *strURL;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

**Step 3** :- Write down this code in SecondVC, .m file.
URL store in _strURL property and load URL in Web view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_strURL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```